# Query to select last word in multiple string lines

Tags: mysql, sql

This might not be possible but I thought I would ask. In a MySQL field that may contain one or more lines of text, is there some way to retrieve the last word in all including the multiple line ones? Fetching the last word is easy but this gives only the very last one if multiple lines while I need all lines:

`SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(TRIM(MakesModels), ' ', -1) FROM quotes;`

The field contains vehicle details, such as year, make, model and VIN in that order with carriage returns where there is more than one in that order and it is a list of the VINs that I am after. If not possible, then getting all of each line of text will work if ordered by the VIN in it.

Here is a rough example as posted in the answer by Renuka Jatoth but I'll add a snippet from it here too. Note that some of these may be within the same entry and I need to pull out each one. The expected output is the same data but with the VIN preceding it and sorted by it.

```
2003 Pontiac Grand Prix Hardtop WVGAV7AX1FW055522
1984 Chevrolet Impala 2-Door Hardtop KNALN4D79E5857681
2007 Mercury WAUDF48H97A796136
2013 Porsche 1G6DJ8E37C0181444
2007 Honda Accord Sedan WAUSF78E38A883031
2013 Isuzu Box Truck 1GYFK26259R997864
2021 Nissan Leaf Sedan SAJWA0FAXAH271577
```

Comment: seems like you need a regex here .. Can you add some simple data and the expected output ?

Comment: I would just fetch the whole text content, and explode it in client code. Some tasks are not convenient to do with SQL.

Comment: I added some sample data but exploding it in the PHP may not help (or maybe it will - I'll look into it) as this is to be used in a select box pull down to fetch the entry for editing.

Answer (score 0):

Considering this is your Database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `mock_data` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `MakesModels` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci,
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

Table data:

```
insert  into `mock_data`(`id`,`MakesModels`) values (1,'2003\r\n GMC\r\n Pontiac\r\n WVGAV7AX1FW055522\r\n\r\n1984\r\n Ford\r\n Chevrolet\r\n KNALN4D79E5857681\r\n\r\n2007\r\n Mercury\r\n Mercury\r\n WAUDF48H97A796136\r\n\r\n2013\r\n Hyundai\r\n Porsche\r\n 1G6DJ8E37C0181444\r\n\r\n2007\r\n Chevrolet\r\n Honda\r\n WAUSF78E38A883031\r\n\r\n2013\r\n Ford\r\n Isuzu\r\n 1GYFK26259R997864\r\n\r\n2001\r\n Isuzu\r\n Nissan\r\n SAJWA0FAXAH271577\r\n\r\n1989\r\n Honda\r\n GMC\r\n 5GAER13798J617186\r\n\r\n2004\r\n Toyota\r\n Chevrolet\r\n 1GYEK63N66R048238\r\n\r\n1990\r\n Subaru\r\n Saab\r\n WDDEJ7KB2CA880763\r\n\r\n1986\r\n Pontiac\r\n Ford\r\n WVGEF9BP1DD542365\r\n\r\n2010\r\n GMC\r\n Toyota\r\n 1G6AJ5S39D0125125\r\n\r\n2012\r\n Volvo\r\n Jaguar\r\n 1FTEX1CM1BK022633\r\n\r\n2006\r\n Lamborghini\r\n Saab\r\n JN8AZ2KR9BT588651\r\n\r\n1987\r\n Ford\r\n Nissan\r\n 2T2BK1BA2FC030464\r\n\r\n1992\r\n Mercedes-Benz\r\n Chevrolet\r\n 3C3CFFBR6ET611594\r\n\r\n2005\r\n Land Rover\r\n GMC\r\n 19XFB2E51EE238734\r\n\r\n2006\r\n Suzuki\r\n Geo\r\n 1N6AA0CA3DN902041\r\n\r\n2012\r\n Jeep\r\n Mercedes-Benz\r\n 1N4AL2EP0DC036326\r\n\r\n1992\r\n Chevrolet\r\n Dodge\r\n 4T1BK1EB9FU145621\r\n\r\n1968\r\n Ford\r\n Ford\r\n SCBBP9ZA8CC386256\r\n\r\n1986\r\n Mitsubishi\r\n Saab\r\n WBAWB73558P773017\r\n\r\n1992\r\n Chevrolet\r\n Ford\r\n W');
```

Then finding the VIN Number from all the rows will be

```
SELECT 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(MakesModels, ' ', 1) AS YEAR,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(MakesModels, '\r\n\r\n', 1) AS nn,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(MakesModels, '\r\n\r\n', 1), ' ', -1) AS vin FROM `mock_data` m ORDER BY vin;
```

Note: I am using Windows so end line character will be "**\r\n**". If you are using Linux then it will be **"\n"**.

Comment: Welcome to this group and thank you for the help! It seems to works almost perfectly and no need for an intermediate table. Since this data changes often, best to fetch it directly. However, I can't tell if it's pulling out entries with multiple vehicles in them, each of which will be on a separate line in the same field. One thing is that there are not always the same number of details for a vehicle so the VIN needs to be whatever is the last item in the line as I see it is pulling up entries that have a VIN that are not in the vin column. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh, I see it's because some lines have a space after that it is not pulling up the VIN so I'll add a trim.